# Uncaught ReferenceError: data_period is not defined

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vite

In local machine it works well, but in prod I have this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: data_period is not defined
> at V.onUpdate:modelValue.n..n. [as _assign]
> at HTMLSelectElement.

This is my computed

```
order_today()
{
    return this.getData(this.data_period)
}
```

**Template**

```
<select v-model="data_period" class="form-select">
    <option value="order_today">За текущий день</option>
    <option value="order_week">За неделю</option>
    <option value="order_month">За месяц</option>
    <option value="order_all">За все время</option>
</select>
<p class="side-menu-value">
    {{ priceWithSpaces(order_today) }}
</p>
```

**Methods**

```
priceWithSpaces(x)
{
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
},

getData(column)
{
    if (this.city === 'all') {
        let count = 0;
        Object.values(this.brandData[this.brand]).forEach(value => {
            count += value[column];
        })

        return count;
    }

    return this.brandData[this.brand][this.city][column];
}
```

data:

```
city: 'all',
data_period: 'order_today',
brandData: {
            'brand': {
              'city': {
                'team': 155,
                'guest_count': 0,
                'guest_last_day_count': 0,
                'tables_count': 0,
                'order_month': 0,
                'order_week': 0,
                'order_all': 0,
                'order_last_month': 0,
                'order_today': 0,
                'order_last_day': 0,
                'average_sum': 0,
                'all_sum': 0,
                'today_sum': 0
              },
}
```

I don't understand what's wrong?

I tried change variable name, same problem

Comment: Miracle in that when i run it with `npm run dev` it works well, but bundled with `npm run build` throws error